# knitr rmarkdown presentation opts_chunk$set error

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am writing a presentation in rmarkdown and compiling to pdf using 'Knit PDF' (Beamer). The code is as following

````
   ---
   title: "Title"
   author: "Author"
   date: 'Date'
   output:
   beamer_presentation:
   template: default.beamer
   ioslides_presentation: default
   themeoptions: compress
   widescreen: yes
   ---

   ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
   opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE)
   ```    

  ## Slide 1
  A

  ## Slide 2
  B
````

But I get the following error

```
  Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'opts_chunk not found Calls: Anno
  <nymous> .... Execution halted
```

I have set the 'Weave Rnw files using' field to 'knitr'. Any ideas on how I might fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `library(knitr)` to the code chunk `opts_chunk` fixed it

`{r setup, include=FALSE}
   library(knitr)
   opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE)`